# How do i display a variable in a <p> element after requesting the data from a POST request using razor(C#) and html

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, razor, server-side

I noticed that this would work if i don't use `Request["name"];` But obviously I need to get the information from my form. I want to display the 'name' in a confirmation message. I am using visual studio asp.net empty webapp

**This is the razor code**

```
 @{
    string title = "This is the title";

    string name = "";
    if (IsPost)
    {

        name = Request["name"];
        string email = Request["email"];
        string message = Request["message"];
    }
}


<p>@name</p>
```

let me know if i should include any other code, but i think this is all you need to see.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out a much easier solution then the other answers.

```
@{
    string title = "This is the title";

    var names = "";
    var emails = "";

    if (IsPost)
    {
        var name = Request["name"];
        var email = Request["email"];
        string message = Request["message"];

        names = name;
        emails = email;
    }
}
```

By reinitializing the `Request["name"];` into another variable, it allows me to use the `names` variable or `emails` variable in my html. This makes the use of MVC redundant and is more simple.

```
<p>Name: @names</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Controller :

```
public ActionResult Test()
    {
        return View();
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Test(string Name, string Message, string email)
    {
        ViewBag.Name = Name;
        ViewBag.Message = Message;
        ViewBag.email = email;
        return View();
    }
```

Razor view:

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    <input type="text" name="Name" />
    <input type="text" name="Message" />
    <input type="email" name="email" />
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
}

<p>@ViewBag.Name</p><br>
<p>@ViewBag.Message</p><br>
<p>@ViewBag.email<p>
```

Comment: This doesnt work, probably because i am working in an asp.net web app environment

Comment: sorry I was misunderstood now check again I edited my answer. I hope this is will help you. thank you

Comment: this is the error i get   ''HtmlHelper' does not contain a definition for 'BeginForm' and no extension method 'BeginForm' accepting a first argument of type 'HtmlHelper' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)'

Comment: which version of Mvc are you using. it was 100% tested code on MVC5..which is good to go.

Comment: Maybe i should have specified that im using visual studio, my bad. Im using the asp.net blank web app in visual  studio

Comment: ok mate..!! you can "Upvote" of this answer it will be helpful for others in future.!! thanks.

Comment: I will as soon as the answer proves useful. Right now it doesnt work

Comment: use this namespace "using System.Web.Mvc;" on your controller.

Comment: yea doesnt change anything. The controller isnt highlighted, its all white, so clearly its not being recognized

Comment: Figured out an much easier solution that doesnt require MVC. I posted it as an answer